# MySQL-запрос на две таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть два запроса `"SELECT т1.поле1, т2.поле2, т3.поле3 FROM таблица1 AS т1 WHERE поле4=1"` и `"SELECT т2.поле1 FROM таблица2 AS т2 WHERE т2.поле2=т1.поле2"` 
Как собрать запрос в один?

Comment: Ну это делать не обязательно, можно просто выполнить запросы по порядку. Чем вас это не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT т1.поле1, т1.поле2, т1.поле3,т2.поле1 FROM таблица1 AS т1 LEFT JOIN таблица2 AS т2 ON (т2.поле2=т1.поле2 AND т1.поле4=1)
```

как то так. Смотрите в сторону JOIN и LEFT JOIN в частности

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно просто "склеить" две таблицы используйте оператор UNION
[Синтаксис тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/UNION.html)